# Function to convert decimal to hex value (error in my program)

Tags: c++, string, hex, decimal

This is just a pretty simple function to convert decimal to hex. I just wanted to store the numbers (0-9) into a string, and then wrote a simple function to retrieve the letter-values for numbers 10-16. **For some reason, the compiler is saying that the retriveHexChar function is not declared in scope (when I use it in my decimalToHex function).** There also may be other issues with my program/functions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

char retrieveHexChar(int num);
void decimalToHex(int number, string s);

int
main()
{

    string s;
    int num = 235;

    decimalToHex(num, s);

}

void
decimalToHex(int number, string s)
{

    if (number > 0) {

        int temp = number % 16;
        s += temp;
        number = number / 16;

        if (temp >= 10)

            s += retriveHexChar(temp);


        decimalToHex(number, s);

    }

    for (int i = s.length(); i > 0; i--)
        cout << s[i];

}

char
retrieveHexChar(int num)
{

    char tempChar;

    switch (num) {

    case '10':
        tempChar = 'A';
        break;

    case '11':
        tempChar = 'B';
        break;

    case '12':
        tempChar = 'C';
        break;

    case '13':
        tempChar = 'D';
        break;

    case '14':
        tempChar = 'E';
        break;

    case '15':
        tempChar = 'F';
        break;
    }
    return tempChar;

}
```

Comment: Simple misspelling; you have a missing `e`: `retriveHexChar` vs `retrieveHexChar`

Comment: I looked at it and thought it was nested. I should have indented as an edit and I wold have noticed ;-) thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your function declaration is:

```
char retrieveHexChar(int num);
```

The bogus call is:

```
retriveHexChar(temp);
```

You probably meant:

```
retrieveHexChar(temp);
//   ^
```

Also, `case '10':` is a mistake. Although it compiles, it checks for a *multi-byte character constant*.  You probably meant `case 10:` .

Comment: Thanks guys...Sorry for the careless mistake. I should have caught it before bringing it here.